# Bundle doesn't find compatible versions even though the locked one satisfies all conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am building a gem, `my_gem` which depends on the following:

```
gem.add_dependency 'money-rails'
gem.add_dependency 'monetize'
```

Inside my main app, I specify in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'my_gem', path: '~/my_gem'
gem 'money-rails', '1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4'
gem 'monetize', '1.1.1.upnxt.prerelease.1'
```

My main app's `Gemfile.lock` contains:

```
monetize (1.1.1.upnxt.prerelease.1)
  money (~> 6.5.0)
money-rails (1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  monetize (>= 1.1.1.u, < 1.2.0)
  money (~> 6.5.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
```

However, when I try to `bundle` my main app, I get the following:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "monetize":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
  monetize (= 1.1.1.upnxt.prerelease.1)

In Gemfile:
  money-rails (= 1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4) ruby depends on
    monetize (< 1.2.0, >= 1.1.1.u) ruby

  my_gem (>= 0) ruby depends on
    monetize (>= 0) ruby

  monetize (= 1.1.1.upnxt.prerelease.1) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Why is this happening? The already locked version for `monetize`, `1.1.1.upnxt.prerelease.1` is greater than `0` and `1.1.1.u`, and lower than `1.2.0`.

**UPDATE**

After following the advice in the comments, I've only left `money-rails` in my gem's dependencies. But still, now I see this when running `bundle` from my main app:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "money-rails":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
  money-rails (= 1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4)

In Gemfile:
  my_gem (>= 0) ruby depends on
    money-rails (>= 0) ruby

  money-rails (= 1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

If I try `bundle update money-rails`, it succeeds and it says:

```
Using monetize 1.1.1.upnxt.prerelease.1
Using money-rails 1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4
```

But still, if I then try to run anything with `bundle exec`, it fails with the above error. I just can't understand what's wrong.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that if I specify the same hardcoded `money-rails` version in my gem as in my main app it manages to `bundle`. So now I have:

```
gem.add_dependency 'money-rails', '1.4.2.upnxt.prerelease.4'
```

While it works, I don't want to leave it like this, as I don't want to enforce any fixed version to the apps using this gem. If someone can give me a hint of this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: If `money-rails` already has a dependency on `monetize`, why are you trying to include it in your gem? I think you should be able to just let `money-rails` include the version of `monetize` that it needs instead of specifying it explicitly.

Comment: @ColtonFent I've added an update to my question. Still having issues with this...

Answer (score 0):

So you were initially trying to include a version of the Gem `monetize`, that for whatever reason, did not meet the dependency requirements of `money-rails`. However, `money-rails` already has a dependency on `monetize` so you shouldn't have to add a dependency in your in your gem for `monetize`. You should let `money-rails` figure out what version of it's dependencies to install instead of locking it in manually.

Comment: Indeed, this was the solution which lead to my first update, but I still have no clue what made the second update from my question really work.